# How do I see that a linear function $L: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ is smooth?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How do I see that a linear function $L: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ is smooth ?

I see that $L$ is indeed differentiable with $(DL)_x = L$ by definition of the derivative.

But how do I verify that $L$ is differentiable for every $k \ge 1$ ?

I know for $k=2$ i should prove that $x \mapsto (DL)_x$ i differentiable at every point ?

Comment: *Smooth* does not mean that the differential should be invertible.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected. It was a typo.

Comment: As you pointed out, a linear map is *everywhere* differentiable.

Comment: But the map $(DL)_x$ is not a linear map ??

Comment: It's $L$ itself.

Comment: How exactly are you defining smooth function?

Comment: That $f$ is $k$-times differentiable for every $k \in \mathbb N$.

So @jibounet, the $2$'nd order derivative is the linear mapping $x \mapsto 0$ ?

Answer (score 7):

The derivative, as a function, is a mapping
$$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
DL\colon \R^n\to\mathscr{L}(\R^n,\R^m)
$$
where $\mathscr{L}(\R^n,\R^m)$ is the space of linear maps (with its natural structure of Banach space induced by the operator norm). In the case $L$ is linear, the mapping $DL\colon x\mapsto (DL)_x=L$ is constant, so its derivative is zero.

Comment: Can you explain me why $(DL)_x = L$ constant, please? Thank you!

Comment: @g.pomegranate Just show that $L$ satisfies the property of being the derivative of itself at every point. The intuition is that the derivative is the linear map that best approximates the function at a point; if a function is already linear, then it best approximates itself, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the second Gateaux derivative,
$$
d^2_G L(u) \colon (h,k) \mapsto \frac{d}{dt} \Big|_{t=0} d_G L(u+tk)h = \frac{d}{dt} \Big|_{t=0} Lh =0.
$$
Hence the second Gateaux derivative is identically zero, and therefore $d^2 L$ is also zero.

Comment: I think using Gateaux derivative here is a) an overkill; b) making the problem unnecessarily difficult; c) not adapted to the level of OP.

Comment: It is by far the most intuitive extension of directional derivatives. I guess it may be easily understood by everyone who is studying differential calculus.

Comment: +1 for using Gateaux derivatives